# Problem using Scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

Why does scanf give a max value in case of "int" but crash the program in case of "char" when the limit is exceeded?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
int a;
char ch[10];
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("%d",a);
scanf("%s",ch);
printf("%s",ch);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It crashes your program in this case because `scanf()` has an <strike>inherently</strike> unsafe interface for strings. It has no way of knowing that your parameter `ch` is an array large enough to hold a 9-character string plus its terminating nul. As a result, it is perfectly happy to keep reading characters from `stdin` and storing them in memory well past the end of the array.

If your program crashes, you are actually lucky. In the worst case, the attacker has used a carefully crafted string to manipulate the content of the stack in such a way that he has gained control of your computer. This is an example of a buffer overflow attack. It sounds unlikely, but it has been documented to occur on a large number of occasions.

Used for only numbers, `scanf` is generally safe enough, but it is not very good at handling errors in the input. As a result, it is usually a good idea to use something like `fgets()` to read the input (it has a buffer length parameter to control overflow) and `sscanf()` to parse from that buffer, testing its return values for sanity as you go.

**Edit:** As the comment from [R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) points out, I overstated the dangers inherent to the `scanf` interface. With care to correctly use the field width specifier on all strings, `scanf` becomes safer. But then you take responsibility for guaranteeing that the specified width does fit within the buffer. For the example, you should write `scanf("%9s",ch);` because your buffer was declared to be ten bytes long and you need room for the terminating nul.

Note that you should also be testing the return value from `scanf()`. It returns the number of fields it successfully matched, or `EOF` if an I/O error occurred. It might return 0 if the user entered "abc" when it expected a number, for instance.

Comment: @R., well, true. Note that it is rather inconvenient to keep the size of the buffer in sync with the format specifier. That is one reason to strongly recommend using `fgets()` followed by a more robust parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not reading a character, you're reading a string. And scanf does not "know" that you only have space for 10 characters (including the null). This is the joy of C programming.

You can protect yourself in this case by adding a width modifier:

```
%9s
```