# Segmentation fault while using printing output of strlen in C++ 4.8.1

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, strlen

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>

int main(){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        char *str;
        scanf("%s",str);
        int l,n,nop=1;
        l=strlen(str);
        printf("Length %d",l); //causing segmentation fault
        if(l%2==0)n=l/2;
        else n=(l-1)/2;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)nop=nop+abs(str[i]-str[l-1-i]);
        printf("%d\n",nop);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting error when I print the length of string. If I remove that line the code works but with incorrect output.
The code works fine with DevC++

Comment: `char *str; scanf("%s",str);` Lovely. Pointers don't automagically point to memory that can store an indefinitely-sized string.

Comment: Where are you initializing `str`?

Comment: @chris meant to tell you that you are short an & before str, and this leads to memory corruptiom.

Comment: @bmargulies, Well, no, because `%s` expects `char *`, not `char **`, but yeah, I edited with more info.

Comment: Yes, that was intentional.

Comment: Be careful if you ever use `scanf` in real-world code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456169/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/2430303/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `str` by allocating space for it:

```
char *str = (char *)malloc(SIZE);
```

Otherwise it will invoke *undefined behavior*. Also, declare `l` of `size_t` type because `strlen` returns type is `size_t` and change `%d` to `%zu` in `printf`

Comment: I get the following error:
invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Cast the return value of `malloc` to `char *`.

Comment: Yes, it works now. But my code worked with the correct output on DevC++ Why did that happen?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include (char *)

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma It's *undefined behavior*, meaning anything can happen. Appearing to work and silently corrupting your memory is "anything", as is crashing or formatting your hard drive or setting your computer on fire or making demons fly out of your nose.

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma; I already edited that. * But my code worked with the correct output on DevC++ Why did that happen?*: In case of UB, anything could happen. Result may be either expected or unexpected or it may be compiler dependent. Nothing can be said.